# Shorter solution to if,else if,else if

Tags: java, parsing, math, if-statement, int

I'm looking for a way to shorten this code up and avoid repeating code and if  statements. What I'm doing is creating a calculator that searches strings for operators "* / + - " and executes them accordingly. Any ideas?

```java
if (exp.charAt(i) == '*') {
    newResult = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i)) * Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i + 1, exp.length()));
    primeResult = newResult;
    System.out.println(primeResult);
} else if (exp.charAt(i) == '/') {
    newResult = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i)) / Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i + 1, exp.length()));
    primeResult = newResult;
    System.out.println(primeResult);
} else if (exp.charAt(i) == '+') {
    newResult = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i)) + Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i + 1, exp.length()));
    primeResult = newResult;
    System.out.println(primeResult);
} else if (exp.charAt(i) == '-') {
    newResult = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i)) - Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i + 1, exp.length()));
    primeResult = newResult;
    System.out.println(primeResult);
}
```

Also, is there a solution to accept a string with more than 2 operands? i.e. 5 + 10 * 2 / 3

Comment: Use `switch()` which may reduce your code

Comment: For multiple operands, decompose the compound statement, doing each operation in correct mathematical order (PEMDAS). Take the result and use it as the left or right operand to the next statement. Simple. Decompose and Evaluate step by step.

Comment: As for the more than one operands you can program up the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). If you want I can add an explanation of it to my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For changing the code you could use a switch statement and putting some of the redundant code before or after the switch.

```
int left = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0,i));
int right = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i+1,exp.length()));
switch(exp.charAt(i)){
    case '*':
        primeResult = left * right;
        break;
    case '/':
        ...
        break;
    case '+':
        ...
        break;
    case '-':
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ... // Error Handling.
}
System.out.println(primeResult);
```

Comment: Thanks this is great!. How could it work with a for loop? say for(i=0; i < exp.length; i++) ?

Comment: You need to calculate where the operator is and what part of the string constitutes the right and left half of the expression. I don't think it would work for `for(i=0; i < exp.length; i++)` because not all `i` represent operators. You would need a different for loop header.

Comment: You could do the for loop checking `if( isOperator( exp.substring(i, 1) ) ) { doOperation( exp, i ); }`

Comment: @user2291971 I don't know something like `for(i=firstOperatorLoc; i < exp. length; i = getNextOperatorLoc(exp, i))` where firstOperatorLoc is the location of the first operator and getNextOperatorLoc find the next location. However this doesn't do order of operations. Or you could just add the if statement @ShadowCreeper put up.

Answer (score 6):

There's no need of `switch` statements and complex hierrachies of classes.

In order to simplify and shorten your code and calculate simple and complex expressions (represented as `String` objects), you can use the Java's `JavaScript API` and it's `ScriptEngine` class, which basically simulates a `JavaScript` console.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create a script engine manager
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        // create a JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        // evaluate JavaScript code from String
        System.out.println(engine.eval("(5+10)*2/3"));
    }
}
```

This will output: `10.0`

Comment: I like your answer (using the `ScriptEngine`) better than mine, so I deleted it :)

Comment: Ooohhh I like this one. It's a hack, but I like it and it's nice to know it exists. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I learned about it very recently. It can relieve us from the burden to write complex stuff. :)

Comment: This should be on top... Owned my use of ScriptEngine

Comment: To get technical, the Javascript calculation engine may not be equivalent to Java's, but I would assume this would work for the asker's question, and a very nice solution at that!

Answer (score 4):

You could write an `AbstractCalculationOperation` class with `execute` method, with `Add`, `Subtract`, etc extending it.

Then, just parse `leftHand`, `rightHand`, and `calculationOperation` and run `calculationOperation.execute( rightHand, leftHand )`.

```java
public interface CalculationOperation {
    double calculate ( double lh, double rh );
    long calculate ( long lh, long rh );
}

public class Add implements CalculationOperation {
    public static final CalculationOperation INSTANCE = new Add();
    public double calculate ( double rh, double lh ) { return lh + rh; }
    public long calculate ( long rh, long lh ) { return lh + rh; }
}
```

And then:

```java
int lh = exp.substring(0, i);
int rh = exp.substring(i+1);
CalculationOperation op;
switch( exp.charAt(i) ) {
    case '*': op = Multiply.INSTANCE; break;
    case '/': op = Divide.INSTANCE; break;
    case '+': op = Add.INSTANCE; break;
    case '-': op = Subtract.INSTANCE; break;
}
newResult = op.calculate( rh, lh );
primeResult = newResult;
System.out.println(primeResult);
```

Alternate enum variant:

```java
public enum Calculation {
    ADD('+') {
        public int calculate( int lhs, int rhs ) { return lhs + rhs; }
        public long calculate( long lhs, long rhs ) { return lhs + rhs; }
        public float calculate( float lhs, float rhs ) { return lhs + rhs; }
        public double calculate( double lhs, double rhs ) { return lhs + rhs; }
    },
    SUBTRACT('-') {
        public int calculate( int lhs, int rhs ) { return lhs - rhs; }
        public long calculate( long lhs, long rhs ) { return lhs - rhs; }
        public float calculate( float lhs, float rhs ) { return lhs - rhs; }
        public double calculate( double lhs, double rhs ) { return lhs - rhs; }
    },
    MULTIPLY('*') {
        public int calculate( int lhs, int rhs ) { return lhs * rhs; }
        public long calculate( long lhs, long rhs ) { return lhs * rhs; }
        public float calculate( float lhs, float rhs ) { return lhs * rhs; }
        public double calculate( double lhs, double rhs ) { return lhs * rhs; }
    },
    DIVIDE('/') {
        public int calculate( int lhs, int rhs ) { return lhs / rhs; }
        public long calculate( long lhs, long rhs ) { return lhs / rhs; }
        public float calculate( float lhs, float rhs ) { return lhs / rhs; }
        public double calculate( double lhs, double rhs ) { return lhs / rhs; }
    };

    private final char textValue;
    Calculation ( char textValue )
    {
        this.textValue = textValue;
    }

    public abstract int calculate ( int lht, int rhs );
    public abstract long calculate ( long lht, long rhs );
    public abstract float calculate ( float lht, float rhs );
    public abstract double calculate ( double lht, double rhs );

    public static Calculation fromTextValue( char textValue ) {
        for( Calculation op : values() )
            if( op.textValue == textValue )
                return op;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unknown operation: " + textValue );
    }
}
```

and then:

```java
int lh = exp.substring(0, i);
int rh = exp.substring(i+1);
Calculation op = Calculation.fromTextValue( exp.substring(i,1) );
newResult = op.calculate( lh, rh );
primeResult = newResult;
System.out.println(primeResult);
```

Comment: To make it even cleaner, you can turn it into an `enum Calculation` with `ADD`, `SUBTRACT`, etc all implementing the calculate methods and a `public static Calculation fromText(char textOp)` method inside the `enum` that handles the `switch`.

Comment: The plus side to the enum variant is that to add say `LOGARITHM` or `EXPONENT` you just add an entry to the enum (implementing all 4 required methods - int,float,long,double). No need to worry about updating the switch statement everywhere it is used because it is only used in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Shorten the code by grabbing the variables separately from doing the operation. This will not reduce your "if" statements, but it will drastically reduce the line numbers.

Don't do multiple variables until you understand trees... I've never worked with them personally, but I think "expression trees" are what you'll be after. (note: I just checked on google, yep, Expression Trees)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple how to avoid too much code repetition:

```
Integer op1= Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i);
Integer op2=Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i+1, exp.length()));
if(exp.charAt(i)=='*')  {
            newResult=op1 * op2;
} else 
....
primeResult = newResult;
System.out.println(primeResult);
```

But to do something more general, robust and useful, with arbitrary nesting levels, you should use some real parser. [For example.](http://jparsec.codehaus.org/jparsec2+Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        float primeResult;
        String exp = "4-2";
        int i = 1;
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        char[] myVar = new char[] { '*', '/', '-', '+' };

        for (int myVarCtr = 0; myVarCtr < myVar.length; myVarCtr++) {

            if (exp.charAt(i) == myVar[myVarCtr]) {

                try {
                    primeResult = Float.parseFloat(engine.eval(
                            (Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i)))
                                    + Character.toString(myVar[myVarCtr])
                                    + (Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i + 1,
                                            exp.length())))).toString());
                    System.out.println(primeResult);
                } catch (ScriptException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }
```